# jQuery multiple ShowHide Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I have a show/hide script for our forum's users signatures,

The code goes like this:

```
<fieldset>
<legend align="right"><a href="member.php?$session[sessionurl]u=$post[userid]">Signature of $post[musername] </a></legend>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){   
        $("signature").toggle(600);
        (this).parent().prev('.toggle').toggle('slow');
    });
});
</script>
<div class="spoiler" align="center">
<font size="2" face="Tahoma"> <a style="cursor:pointer">Press here to see $post[musername]'s signature</a>
</if></font></div></div><br>
<signature style="display: none;" align="center">$post[signature]</signature>
</fieldset>
```

The code works well, but when one press the hide/show text, all signatures show up which is irritating. Any ideas?

I tried the code on http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_toggle
and doubled the code (typed it twice), All signatures appear/disappear at the same time!

Comment: What does the code do, and what do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You are instructing to show / hide all signatures. To show or hide a specific one you can do:

```
  <a data-id="link1" style="cursor:pointer">Press here to see $post[musername]'s signature</a>
   <signature id="link1" style="display: none;" align="center">$post[signature]</signature>

   <a data-id="link2" style="cursor:pointer">Press here to see $post[musername]'s signature</a>
   <signature id="link2" style="display: none;" align="center">$post[signature]</signature>
```

and then

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function() {
        var signatureId=this.getAttribute ("data-id");
        $("#"+signatureId).toggle(600);   
        .
        .
    });
});
```

the trick is to assign a different Id to every signature, and to tell the `<a>` what id is it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<fieldset>
<legend align="right"><a href="member.php?$session[sessionurl]u=$post[userid]">Signature of $post[musername] </a></legend>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){   
        **$(this).parents('block').find("signature").toggle(600);**
        $(this).parent().prev('.toggle').toggle('slow');
    });
});
</script>
**<div class="block">** 
<div class="spoiler" align="center">
<font size="2" face="Tahoma"> <a style="cursor:pointer">Press here to see $post[musername]'s signature</a>
</if></font></div><br>
<signature style="display: none;" align="center">$post[signature]</signature>
**</div>**
</fieldset>

 Please refer above code 
 I added 3 new lines in code
 I added one parent div of <a> and signature class div
 then i accessed both using their parent div having class block
 and yes in your html </div> is 2 time, i reduced 1 </div>
```